# string format escape sequence

Tags: c#, asmx, html-escape-characters

I have webmethod from which I am fetching one record and display in my asp:label.

I have a `List<string>` in my WebMethod and while reading data I am converting it with `String.Format`

```
while(dr.Read())
{
    rst.Add(string.Format("{0}",dr["Practice_short_name"]));
}
```

However, when I am displaying data in my label I am getting this:

> ["CEC2"]

but i want it to be like this:

> CEC2

How to excape brackets [] and "" from my output?

Comment: I think you should give us a bit more code; for example the code in the page with the label. Are you calling ToString (explicitly or implicitly) on the list?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
 rst.Add(string.Format("{0}",dr["Practice_short_name"].ToString())
```

Comment: .ToString() will be called on each object passed to String.Format, so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data itself is **not** of the form ["VALUE"], you shouldn't need to escape anything.  String.format is not necessary for just one value substitution either.

Why not define an extension method which will also handle null values in one move?

```
public static string GetText(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    if (row.IsNull(columnName))
        return string.Empty;
    return row[columnName] as string ?? string.Empty;
}
```

Then you can simply write:

```
rst.Add(dr.GetText("Practice_short_name"));
```